# Fill in missing values group-wise in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a couple of dataframes.

`df1` has columns `Company`, and `ProductID`. There is only one `productID` per company in this dataframe.

`df2` has columns `CompanyID` and `ProductID`. There can be multiple `productID`s per `companyID`, and multiple `companyID`s can correspond to the same company.

`df2` has many more `productID`s than `df1`. I want to assign a company to each `productID`.

Is there a way I can  assign a company to each company ID, and then assign that company to every other product ID that belongs to that company?

For example:

```
data1 = {'Company' : ['Company 1', 'Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3', 'Company 4', 'Company 5'],
      'ProductID' : ['ASG1', 'HDS8', 'BHF5', 'VHJ4', 'LKH6', 'LKD4']}

data2 = {'CompanyID' : ['C1', 'C1', 'C1a', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C3', 'C4', 'C1', 'C5', 'C5', 'C4', 'C2'],
'ProductID' : ['ASG1', 'FHJ5', 'HDS8', 'BHF5', 'CCD4', 'KKL4', 'VHJ4', 'LKH6', 'CBN1', 'MNZ2', 'LKD4', 'LMJ1', 'XXC1']}

outputdata = {'CompanyID' : ['C1', 'C1', 'C1a', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C3', 'C4', 'C1', 'C5', 'C5', 'C4', 'C2'],
'ProductID' : ['ASG1', 'FHJ5', 'HDS8', 'BHF5', 'CCD4', 'KKL4', 'VHJ4', 'LKH6', 'CBN1', 'MNZ2', 'LKD4', 'LMJ1', 'XXC1'],
'Company' : ['Company 1', 'Company 1', 'Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 1', 'Company 3', 'Company 3', 'Company 4', 'Company 1', 'Company 5', 'Company 5', 'Company 4', 'Company 2']}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
outputdf = pd.DataFrame(data=outputdata)
```

The `companyID`s aren't actually as informative as they are in this example, so both dataframes are needed to match them up.

Edit: I have added an example of what I want the output to look like (outputdf).

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get an error: `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`. Will you please correct that?

Comment: @user17242583 Sorry - missing comma. That's working now. (Also note a small edit to one of the company IDs)

Comment: Will you please add a dataframe containing your expected output? It would help visualize this a lot.

Comment: @user17242583 Apologies again! Added now.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge on `ProductID`, then fill everything in with the most common value for each `CompanyID`:

```
df2['Company'] = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', left_on='ProductID', right_on='ProductID').groupby('CompanyID')['Company'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
   CompanyID ProductID    Company
0         C1      ASG1  Company 1
1         C1      FHJ5  Company 1
2        C1a      HDS8  Company 1
3         C2      BHF5  Company 2
4         C1      CCD4  Company 1
5         C3      KKL4  Company 3
6         C3      VHJ4  Company 3
7         C4      LKH6  Company 4
8         C1      CBN1  Company 1
9         C5      MNZ2  Company 5
10        C5      LKD4  Company 5
11        C4      LMJ1  Company 4
12        C2      XXC1  Company 2
```

Comment: This works on this example, but annoyingly doesn't work on my actual dataset (possibly because some groups may contain only NaN values in the CompanyID column). Is there a way to deal with this? I appreciate it may not be possible to answer without an example of a dataset that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Yeah, could you show a sample? It's really hard to even comprehend the exact problem without seeing the data.